# Как решить проблему c телеграмм ботом на php?

Tags: php, telegram

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

if(isset($data)) {
    $message = Array(
        'chat_id' => $data->{'message'}->{'chat'}->{'id'},
        'message_id' => $data->{'message'}->{'message_id'},
        'text' => $data->{'message'}->{'text'},
        'from' => $data->{'message'}->{'from'}->{'id'},
        'username' => $data->{'message'}->{'from'}->{'username'},
        'firstname' => $data->{'message'}->{'from'}->{'first_name'},
        'lastname' => $data->{'message'}->{'from'}->{'last_name'},
        'new_chat_member' => $data->{'message'}->{'new_chat_member'},
        'left_chat_member' => $data->{'message'}->{'left_chat_member'}
    );

    $callback = Array(
        'id' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'id'},
        'type' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'data'},
        'chat_id' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'message'}->{'chat'}->{'id'},
        'from' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'from'}->{'id'},
        'username' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'from'}->{'username'},
        'firstname' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'from'}->{'first_name'},
        'lastname' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'from'}->{'last_name'},
        'message_id' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'message'}->{'message_id'},
        'message_text' => $data->{'callback_query'}->{'message'}->{'text'}
    );
}
```

Ошибка:
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$last_name in *** on line 95
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$new_chat_member in**  on line 96
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$left_chat_member in  **on line 97
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in**  on line 101
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in  **on line 101
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in**  on line 102
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in  **on line 102
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in**  on line 103
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'message' of non-object in  **on line 103
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'chat' of non-object in**  on line 103
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in  **on line 103
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in**  on line 104
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'from' of non-object in  **on line 104
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in**  on line 104
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in  **on line 105
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'from' of non-object in**  on line 105
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'username' of non-object in  **on line 105
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in**  on line 106
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'from' of non-object in  **on line 106
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object in**  on line 106
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in  **on line 107
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'from' of non-object in**  on line 107
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'last_name' of non-object in  **on line 107
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in**  on line 108
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'message' of non-object in  **on line 108
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'message_id' of non-object in**  on line 108
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$callback_query in  **on line 109
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'message' of non-object in *** on line 109
[09-Jun-2020 21:12:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'text' of non-object in *** on line 109

```
Что делать?
```

Comment: json_decode передайте второй параметр TRUE и он вам вернет не объект, а ассоциативный массив. А с ним не будет проблем что какие то свойства отсутствуют. А вообще стоит взглянуть на структуру пришедших данных, что то там слишком много нет, что вы ожидаете увидеть

Comment: @Mike, мне полный код данного файла выложить?

Comment: Нет, код не поможет. проблема не в коде, а в тех данных, которые получил file_get_contents возможно их формат не соответствует тому, как вы его используете

Comment: @Mike, а как тогда это исправить?

Comment: Сделайте как я в начале написал, TRUE передайте декоду, потом полученный массив распечатайте var_dump и посмотрите чего там не хватает

Comment: @Mike, можно кодом, я просто не пойму, что именно надо сделать.

Comment: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE); print var_dump($data);`

Comment: Ну и дальше если на входе каких то данных может не быть, расставлять на все проверки с isset

Comment: Теперь это https://pastebin.com/KKJJt3Ar

Comment: Разумеется. Мы же теперь массив получили а не объект. остальной код надо адаптировать. И вообще я это предложил не для исправления ошибок, а для отладки, что бы можно было понять чего именно не хватает в данных. Прочитайте ошибки, там например 'Undefined property: stdClass::$last_name' это значит что в пришедших данных нет никакого last_name по пути $data->{'message'}->{'from'}->{'last_name'}

Comment: интересно, вы какое то эстетическое удовольствие получаете от написания `$data->{'message'}` вместо `$data->message` ?